# Random number for token, getting the same number on diferent programing languages, using something like time to achieve this offline

Tags: java, flutter, dart

What I need to achieve is a token app. But this token app needs to work even offline. Another program on the other side is going to ask for this token from the customer, but we want the customer to be able to see his token even if he has no connection to the ethernet.

The app is developed with flutter and dart, and the other side is working in java. So I need something like a function that would return me a 6 digit number, giving it 3 parameters(Time HH: mm, Some customer id, and a key for security purposes). That number needs to be the same on both sides and it should change every minute.

Any help or advice on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to use `AES` or `Blowfish` or any other encryption algorithm on both ends. Take a look here: https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography

Comment: Use a known hashing function.  If it doesn't need to be cryptographically strong (which would be the case if you want only a 6 digit number), then you could pick something simple and fast.